# Reading and wrinting in Java

Tags: java, csv

I want to compare every word in the book (URL) with the words of the dictionary (Data.csv), so that if a word does not exist in the dictionary it's added to it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: @Karla, what is analysis()? What about it didn't work when you tried using it?

Comment: downshift, I just want to analysis (Compare) the two files and add the new words to dictionary. I googled analysis files in java it was quite complicated and i couldn't implement it. that is what i meant :). So, is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your csv file and your text file and store the data in a set. The advantage of a set is you do not have to care about duplicates. You can then just add the data from text file to the set of data from your dictionary. This way you can avoid making comparisons by yourself. Example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.csv"));
        String line;
        String splitBy = ",";
        Set<String> dataFromDictionary = new HashSet<>(); 

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
             String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
             for(String s : b){
              dataFromDictionary.add(s.toLowerCase()); 
             }
        }
        br.close();

        URL book = new URL("http://manybooks.net/send/1:text:.txt:text/topeliusz2724927249-8/topeliusz2724927249-8.txt)");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(book.openStream(),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)); // added Charsets so that å, ä ... are correct encoded

        Set<String> dataFrombook = new HashSet<>();
        String inputLine;
        int lineNumber = 1;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            lineNumber++;

            if(lineNumber > 54 && lineNumber < 1313){   // just jumped the copyright stuff
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                String[] words = inputLine.split("[\\s\\p{Punct}]+"); // split the line at blank space or punctuations like . , ; ! etc. to get only the words
                for(String s : words){
                    if(s.matches("\\p{L}+")){     // check if the string contains only letters // not to add numbers to your dictionary                   
                        dataFrombook.add(s.toLowerCase());  // change all to lowercase or uppercase because otherwise "Apple" will be treated as different word as "apple"
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();

        String csvFile = "newData.csv"; // write to new file or overwrite Data.csv
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);

        dataFromDictionary.addAll(dataFrombook);
        Set<String> sorted = new TreeSet<>(dataFromDictionary);
        for(String s : sorted){           
            writer.write(s);  
            writer.write("\n"); // no idea how your csv file is structured; this will write each word to a new line; modify if necessary
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all this in the main method you can of course break it into small methods to make it more readable.